# PHP How to handle different languages in config file?

Tags: php, translation

I am working on a project and there are going to be 3 different languages: **English, French and Spanish.**  This will be defined when the user signs up.

Now in my config file I have the following:

```
define("DEFAULT_SLOGAN", "The default slogan will go here.");
```

Until I started realizing that I needed to accept different languages.

The user has an assigned language code (EN, FR, SP).  How would I go about having different language strings for each page?  Would I need to have something like this:

```
define("DEFAULT_SLOGAN_EN", "Slogan in english");
define("DEFAULT_SLOGAN_FR", "Slogan in french");
define("DEFAULT_SLOGAN_SP", "Slogan in spanish");
```

And for each string just have 3 different versions of it?  Not too sure the best way to approach this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be to create

- locale_definitions_EN.php containing

  define("DEFAULT_SLOGAN", "The english default slogan will go here.");
- local_definitions_FR.php containing

  define("DEFAULT_SLOGAN", "The french default slogan will go here.");

etc. and then do something like

```
include "locale_definitions_$userLocale.php";
```

This has the advantage, that you don't need the memory to hold the unused other language constants.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this will be best for me as well.

Comment: This looks like a rather dirty solution. You will eventually face a point where you will want to fall back to English translations when there are no French translations available. You cannot achieve that with this method. Think about the future of your project ;-)

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: This is handled on a different level! since `$userLocale` is **always** available, the fallback would be to set it to EN if FR is unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

A simple strategy that is often used are arrays:

```
$lang['en'] = array(
    'DEFAULT_SLOGAN' => 'The default slogan will go here.',
);
// Same for other languages
```

Then, in your actual code, make sure that $lang is available (you can use the `global` keyword for this) and use these arrays.